# Why do people confuse C-type strings and STL strings

Tags: c++, programming-languages, strings

The last week I saw [at](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4293625/9232) [least](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4293446/9232) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4279647/9232) questions where people were confused about the differences between `char *` and `std::string` or made some related mistakes.

Don't get me wrong, I don't have a problem with this, I just don't get the exact reason for this. Maybe it was just a coincidence.

Comment: It wasn't confusion on my part but dealing with strings (and all their variety) in C++ made me want to go work in a different language.

Comment: This question should only be tagged as C++ as there is no such confusion in C since C does not have an std::string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that things like

```
std::string myString = "Hello, world!";
```

are perfectly valid, it seems rather obvious to me why there is confusion.

Comment: yet that same construct in other languages with primary string types doesn't cause confusion at all.

Comment: But most languages don't have two different string types to confuse beginners.

Answer (score 12):

Because they're both commonly known as "strings" in a language that has no real string type.  It's very understandable that inexperienced coders would be confused by that...